# Why 2 raised to 32 power results in a number in bytes instead of bits?

Tags: c, memory, capacity

I just restart the C programming study. Now, I'm studying the memory storage capacity and the difference between bit and byte. I came across to [this definition](https://techterms.com/help/difference_between_32-bit_and_64-bit_systems#:%7E:text=One%20bit%20in%20the%20register,temporary%20values%20besides%20memory%20addresses.).
There is a calculation to a 32 bits system. I'm very confused, because in this calculation 2^32 = 4294967296 bytes and it means about 4 Gigabyte. My question is: Why 2 raised to 32 power results in a number in bytes instead of bits ?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say that memory is byte-addressable, you can think like byte is the smallest unit of memory so you are not reading by bits but bytes. The reason might be that the smallest data type is 1 byte, even boolean type in c/c++ is 1 byte.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. @Harun Sasmaz

Comment: In C, a byte is a `char` (C11 3.6 byte) and a `char` needs at least 8 bit (C11 Annex E Implementation limits 1). But there are many systems where the smallest unit of memory is smaller, for example a single bit. (Not on a PC, but µC ).

Answer (score 4):

That description is really superficial and misses a lot of important considerations, especially as to how memory is *defined* and *accessed*.

Fundamentally an N-bit value has 2<sup>N</sup> possible states, so a 16-bit value has 65,536 possible states. Additionally, memory is accessed as *bytes*, or 8-bit values. This was not always the case, older machines had different "word" sizes, anywhere from 4 to 36 bits per word, [occasionally more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)), but over time the 8-bit word, or "byte", became the dominant form.

In every case a memory "address" contains one "word" or, on more modern machines, "byte". Memory is measured in these units, like "kilowords" or "gigabytes", for reasons of simplicity even though the individual memory chips themselves are specified in terms of bits. For example, a 1 *gigabyte* memory module often has 8 *gigabit* chips on it. These chips are read at the same time, the resulting data combined to produce a single *byte* of memory.

By that article's wobbly definition this means a 16-bit CPU can only address 64KB of memory, which is wrong. DOS systems from the 1980s used two pointers to represent memory, a [*segment* and an *offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation), and could address 16MB using an effective 24-bit pointer. This isn't the only way in which the raw pointer size and total addressable memory can differ.

Some 32-bit systems also had an alternate [36-bit memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSE-36) that allowed addressing up to 64GB of memory, though an individual process was limited to a 4GB slice of the available memory.

In other words, for systems with a singular pointer to a memory address *and* where the smallest memory unit is a byte *then* the maximum addressable memory is 2<sup>N</sup> bytes.

Thankfully, since 64-bit systems are now commonplace and a computer with > 64GB of memory is not even exotic or unusual, addressing systems are a lot simpler now then when having to work around pointer-size limitations.

Comment: "4 to 36" ---> IIRC, some graphic processors, at the machine level, allowed bit addressing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica In a GPU or FPGA world these rules sort of go out the window. Any references for a CPU that allows for bit-level address pointers?

Comment: See 4-17 of [TIGA](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spvu015c/spvu015c.pdf?ts=1592274179269&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F): "The function definition places no restrictions on the alignment of the address;
the field is permitted to begin at any bit address."

Answer (score 3):

Because the memory is byte-addressable (that is, each byte has its own address).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. @Scott Hunter

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to look at this:

A 32-bit integer can hold one of 2^32 different values. Thus, a `uint32_t` can represent the values from `0` to `4294967295`.

A 32-bit address can represent 2^32 different addresses. And as Scott said, on a byte-addressable system, that means 2^32 different bytes can be addressed. Thus, a process with 32-bit pointers can address up to 4 GiB of virtual memory. Or, a microprocessor with a 32-bit address bus can address up to 4 GiB of RAM.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. @Jonathon Reinhart